# How do I unmap backslash in Vim?

Tags: vim

I've rebound `<Space>` to `<Leader>` as I find it more convenient to hit, in general, than `<Bslash>`, but I find that `\` is still bound to leader, and will trigger completion when I type `\n`, as I've bound `<Leader>n` to `<C-x><C-n>`.

`unmap <Bslash>`, `unmap \`, `unmap \\`, and even `unmap %\` do not unmap backslash, and report error 31: No such mapping, so how can I unmap backslash?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to change `<Leader>` to `<Space>`. You should not change using map.

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
```

You can check the current `<Leader>` settings with the following command.

```
:echo "###" .. mapleader .. "$$$"
```

If it is set correctly, the output will be as follows.

```
### $$$
```